# unkown header,footer height and middle content with scroll?

Tags: css, responsive-design, footer

I am trying to create a page which will be have header and footer div with unknown height (or min-height) and middle content with scroll if the content increases and all these three should fit in screen only.

I tried below and works if the height of header and footer is fixed and if only middle content increases then i get scroll for content div perfectly. How do to handle unknown height part for header and footer to make it fit? I gave min-height but doesn't work.

```
#Pageheader {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100px;
background-color: Blue;
}

#Pagefooter {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100px;
background-color:red;
}

#Pagecontent {
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
bottom: 100px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
overflow: auto;
}
```

and Html side

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="Pageheader">
</div>
<div id="Pagecontent">

</div>
<div id="Pagefooter">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ol' school dirty way is to use Jquery. Detect height of header/footer, place and resize the content div according to window height and the previous heights.

A sophisticated solution is to use Flexbox. Using the align-content: stretch you can create the layout you want. ***You can [check it here.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)***

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck trying the same thing last week. I ended up doing it with css tables (compatible with all browsers including IE8). Here's the CSS for it:

/* Layout-1 | Header Footer */

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table;
}

header, footer {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 30px;
}

div#container {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you wanted a fixed header and footer and for the scrolling to only effect the body section in between, the markup and css would be totally different, and utilize `position: absolute;`

Let me know if this works for you : )